# Smalltalk - Is there a way to determine the data type?

Tags: smalltalk

Is there a way to determine the datatype of an already initialized variable in smalltalk?

Eg:

```
|abc|
abc := #(1 2 3 4 5 6)  'This is the array declared'
(abc isKindOf: Array) ifTrue: [ 'Check the data type of abc against array datatype'
    ^'Success!'
]
```

Reason for the request:
I need to implement the a method only if it is called by an specific datatype.

Comment: Can you expand your example a little bit? Explicit type checks are often a sign of a design issue.

Comment: Tobias, thanks for the suggestion. It was indeed a design issue.
I just needed to add the method within the Array class.

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use

```
abc isMemberOf: Array
```

or

```
abc class == Array
```

This checks if `abc` is an instance of the `Array` class ( a thing that you call datatype).

Also maybe

```
abc respondsTo: #message
```

can be useful for you as it checks whether method called *message* is defined for `abc`.

Comment: That was helpful to identify the datatype/class of the variable.
But I realized that if the method is added to the array class then only an instance of array class [which will always be an array] will be able to call it.

Comment: @AdityaKappagantula no. You can always use `Array someMessage` from wherever you want

Answer (score 2):

There is also a frequent idiom in Smalltalk. Define the method `isArray` on `Object` that returns false; define `isArray` on the class `Array` that returns true. Like that, you are able to send `#isArray` to any object. 
But again, as said above, this idiom highlights a suboptimal design.

Answer (score 1):

Simply add the method to the datatype Array. 
i.e to the class Array.

Then only an instance of an Array will be able to call it.